# html contentEditable document.execCommand change selected opacity

Tags: html, opacity, contenteditable, execcommand

any one worked with changing opacity on contentEditable selected.

I tried with following:

```
document.execCommand('foreColor', false, 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)'); // with rgba
document.execCommand('foreColor', false, '80000000'); // with alpha hex
```

none worked. but i can easily change colour with:

```
document.execCommand('foreColor', false, '000000');
```

Can anyone help me on change opacity with document.execCommand ?

**Update**

On further searching found out:

document.execCommand 'foreColor' add font tag to selected with given colour. But sadly the color attribute of  is not supported in HTML5.

is thats the problem ? what is its alternative ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You will have to use the `styleWithCSS` command, which specifies whether CSS or HTML formatting should be generated by the execCommand method into the document.

Refer the specs here: https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/editing/raw-file/tip/editing.html#the-stylewithcss-command .

So, in this case pass `true` to use the CSS styling instead of generating the `font` tag.

***Snippet:***

```js
function setColor() {
    document.execCommand('styleWithCSS', false, true);
    document.execCommand('foreColor', false, "rgba(0,0,0,0.5)");
}
```

```html
<p contentEditable="true" onmouseup="setColor();">this is some text</p>
```

This will generate HTML with CSS applied, like this:

```
<p contenteditable="true" onmouseup="setColor();">
    this is <span style="color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.498039);">some</span> text
</p>
```

Hope that helps.

.

Comment: @Ahtisham: It works just fine. See here: https://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/cmy9r2e7/3/